# c# Should I use a output in my void method?

Tags: c#, methods, output, void

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int Number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            HalfNumber(Number);
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void HalfNumber(int numberToUse)
    {
        double x = numberToUse / 2.0;
        MessageBox.Show("Half of the number is " + x.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

The code above is an example. 
I thought my instructor said never to use a output in a method because in case of testing code, the code might be on the other side of the world and unable to see whats going on. 
I may have misunderstood her, but I would like someone to explain

Comment: Output and void doesn't exclude each other, but `Output` has many meanings. Showing a message on the display is just one of them and it is not appropriate if none can dismiss that dialog. But Output means also writing to a log file and it is more than justified if in your void method you need to log some error conditions.

Comment: Sounds like you're misunderstanding your instructor. Imagine you see a method called `HalfNumber`, what would you expect it to do? For me it should take a number and return half of it, showing a message box would be an unexpected side-effect

Comment: In this specific case it seems your method should simply do the calculation and return the value to the caller. I don't think it should be void (there are plenty of uses for void, but this doesn't seem to be one). Then the calling code can decide how to display the output. The instructor is right that methods like this are just for doing the business logic, they should not do any interaction with the user directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to know exactly what she meant. However putting a dialog in a function that does something discrete is unexpected.

It would be more logical to return a number from the `HalfNumber` Method, and then show the dialog containing the results

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int Number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        double myHalfNumber = HalfNumber(Number);

        MessageBox.Show("Half of the number is " +myHalfNumber.ToString());

        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.SelectAll();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

private double HalfNumber(int numberToUse)
{      
    return numberToUse / 2.0;
}
```

**Separation of Concerns**

> In software engineering, Separation of Concerns refers to the
>   delineation and correlation of software elements to achieve order
>   within a system. Through proper separation of concerns, complexity
>   becomes manageable

**don't repeat yourself (DRY)**

> A principle of software development aimed at reducing repetition of
>   software patterns, replacing them with abstractions; and several
>   copies of the same data, using data normalization to avoid redundancy.

Putting a `HalfNumber` into its own discrete method allows you to reuses your code, and separates that logical out in to is only maintainable and predictable logic

Answer (score 1):

void means you are can not return any value.
If you want to output you are need to specify it.
After that, you can use return values.

For example:

```
private double HalfNumber(int numberToUse)
{
    double x = numberToUse / 2.0;
    return x;
}
```

And you can use like that

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int Number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        double result = HalfNumber(Number);

        MessageBox.Show("Half of the number is " + result.ToString());
        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.SelectAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private double HalfNumber(int numberToUse)
{
    double x = numberToUse / 2.0;
    return x;
}
```